# Can't update kernel to 2.6.35.27

Tags: kernel, updates

When I try to update I get [this](http://pastebin.com/4RYUhwa1) message, I'm guessing I'm missing something here?

```
Filesystem    Type     Size   Used  Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sdb6     ext4      43G   7.7G    33G  20% /
none      devtmpfs     1.6G   349k   1.6G   1% /dev
none         tmpfs     1.6G   5.9M   1.6G   1% /dev/shm
none         tmpfs     1.6G   218k   1.6G   1% /var/run
none         tmpfs     1.6G      0   1.6G   0% /var/lock
/dev/sdb2  fuseblk     258G   198G    60G  77% /media/Backup
/dev/sda1  fuseblk     321G   175G   146G  55% /media/Media
/dev/sdb1     ext4      96M    84M   6.7M  93% /boot
/dev/sdb7     ext4     175G    81G    86G  49% /home
```

Here's the output:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages will be REMOVED:
linux-image-2.6.35-22-generic
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
5 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 107MB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? y
(Reading database ... 282211 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing linux-image-2.6.35-22-generic ...
Examining /etc/kernel/postrm.d .
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/initramfs-tools 2.6.35-22-generic   /boot/vmlinuz-2.6.35-22-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub 2.6.35-22-generic /boot/vmlinuz-2.6.35-22-generic
/etc/default/grub: 23: Syntax error: newline unexpected
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub exited with return code 2
Failed to process /etc/kernel/postrm.d at /var/lib/dpkg/info/linux-image-2.6.35-22-  generic.postrm line 328.
dpkg: error processing linux-image-2.6.35-22-generic (--remove):
subprocess installed post-removal script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
linux-image-2.6.35-22-generic
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

[Here's](http://pastebin.com/yiPnniNs) the content of etc/default/grub

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the log says

> ```
> gzip: stdout: No space left on device
> ```

you're probably missing space on the root partition. Can you check that or provide the output of `df -Th`?

EDIT1:

As for the `dpkg` error:

You have a syntax error in the `/etc/default/grub` file. Either correct it or post it here.

EDIT2:

The line 23 in `/etc/default/grub` shouldn't look like this:

```
GRUB_GFXMODE=>>1024x768-24<<
```

but like this:

```
GRUB_GFXMODE=1024x768
```

Comment: i checked and still have plenty of space , i added the output to my question

Comment: the line looks like that cause a used a script to fix plymouth, which didn't displayed properly, and the script required me to type the  resolution i wanted like that

Comment: So now it's OK? Any other errors? :)

Comment: if i change it, plymouth will not work properly

Comment: I'm not sure about the syntax here if you need to specify depth, but it could be `1024x768x24`.

Answer (score 5):

You don't have enough room on `/boot` (Where the kernel is stored) for the operation to continue. You'll need to allocate more space in `/boot` before you continue. Typically each kernel needs about 17M of space.

You can delete older kernel installs (sometimes using `sudo apt-get autoremove`) Or by just uninstalling that specific version kernel. It's strongly recommended you keep at least two working kernel versions in case something in your more recent Kernel goes awry.

Comment: i have older kernels stored there, can i delete those to make room for the newer kernel?

Comment: Just uninstall any old kernels you don't need, keep say the newest and 1-2 older as a backup.

Comment: can't seem to remove the oldest kernel i have, it gives me an error

Comment: Can you post the full output of the error message, preferably from the Terminal (`sudo apt-get remove linux-image...`)?

Comment: You might want to remove older linux headers as well, you can find them by running `dpkg -l linux-headers-*|grep ii`. Just do not delete the last kernel version or `linux-{headers,image}-generic`.